# Particle in a box as easy model for molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry

I am trying to use the particle in a box model as a simplified model to calculate the energy difference between HOMOs and LUMOs of a molecule.

The molecule I work with is made out of n phenyl-groups. Displayed in the picture below.

[image]

Now thinking of a particle in a 1-D box, the approx. energy difference between a HOMO and LUMO is described as

$$
\Delta E = \frac{h^2(N+1)}{8m_eL^2}
$$

where N is the amount of $\pi$-electrons in the molecule and L the length of the box. The length of the box as well as the number of $\pi$-electrons depends on the number of phenyl-groups (n). I know how I can get the length of such a molecule, but how can I get the amount of $\pi$-electrons?

Comment: Is it possible to simply count the number of pi-bonded electrons on an orbital diagram?